# Stopping hibernate from persisting changes in a associated collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I am loading some hibernate objects through hibernate search and then showing them in the UI. There, our user selects one object and removes some elements from a @ManyToMany association.

Of course, as written in the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-modifying) when the session is flushed, changes are persisted automatically even if I don't call Session#save in the object found.

But that is not the behavior I need. I need my user to remove the objects from the association but only temporally, only for making a report from the modified object without changing my database. So the removed objects in the association do not show in my report.

How can I make this happen?

I was thinking in mark the associated objects as [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) and build a new entity and  make changes there as all the operation in this particular UI are read-only.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the collection with `cascade="evict"`.  Then remove the objects as you like, generate your report, then `evict()` the object before flushing.

Comment: Just a note, I am using hibernate 3.6 so is CascadeType.DETACH instead of Evict.